# Node puppeteer install newer version of Chromium

Tags: node.js, chromium, puppeteer

I tried to install the newest Chromium version with puppeteer with no success.

I tried to use the following:

```
 puppeteer.launch({
   executablePath: '/path/Chromium.app'
 });
```

Or use the `PUPPETEER_DOWNLOAD_HOST` env, but none of them worked.

How can I make puppeteer work with the latest version? ( I'm on mac )

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the full executable path which is located in the Chromium.app directory:

```
await puppeteer.launch({
  executablePath: '/path/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium',
});
```